# Cheerio How do I iterate through the queryselector?

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I am trying to iterate through **td[class="titleColumn"]**. Here is my current code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    let movieURL = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250';

    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(movieURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let title = document.querySelector('td[class="titleColumn"]').innerText;

        return{
            title
        }
    })

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close()
})();
```

I only get one title. How would I iterate through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using querySelectorAll:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('td[class="titleColumn"]')].map(td => td.innerText)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because `document.querySelector` stops at the first item found.
Use `document.querySelectorAll` instead and it should work.

Comment: I got no response. Is there something else I am supposed to do?

Comment: The `console.log(data)` prints nothing ? Add a for loop for the iteration (or a `data.forEach(callback)`)